# Show the length of a contour, given by traversing once round a circle radius r, is 2πr

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have tried this problem using the definition for length of a contour 
$$
L(\gamma) = \int |\gamma'(t)| dt
$$
Along the contour $\gamma =Z +re^{it}$

But I cannot get it to work out at $2\pi r$.

Comment: how did you calculate $\gamma'$? What are the maximum and minimum values of $t$ defining your contour?

Comment: Max and min values would be 0 and 2π I guess since its a circle. And γ' = tre^it I think?

Comment: Don't you mean $ire^{it}$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: So then, what happens to $i$ and $e^{it}$ when you take absolute values of the formula in Rolf Hoyer's comment?

Comment: I don't know, that is my question

Comment: @emma You have to know something, write the very last step you can get  to, please.

Comment: I have done if you read the comments...

Answer (score 1):

First we set:
$$z(t) = r \cdot {e^{it}}\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\left\| {z(t)} \right\| = r} \\ 
  {z'(t) = i \cdot z(t)} 
\end{array}} \right.$$
And with
$$\gamma (t) = {z_0} + z(t)$$
we have
$$\gamma '(t) = z'(t) = i \cdot z(t)$$
and
$$\left\| {\gamma '(t)} \right\| = \left\| i \right\| \cdot \left\| {z(t)} \right\| = r$$
Ready to integrate:
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\left\| {\gamma '(t)} \right\|dt = } \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {r \cdot dt}  = r \cdot \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {dt}  = 2\pi  \cdot r$$